What is the name of this movie with microwave satellite and ice age?
The name in Japanese looked like silent world but its not listed as that in IMDb. A scientist is watching a comet return and is called to government meeting. They want to direct the comet heading for Earth using an experimental microwave satellite. But it seems like it failed and the Earth is hit by the comet and the planet plunged into a full ice age. 3 years later, the microwave satellite is being used by terrorists to take down the New Northern American Alliance. I thought it was best scifi movie for its science fiction content. Acting was OK and CGI looked like CGI but appropriate and not terrible.  

Post Impact, (2004), with Dean Cain.  It has the satellite weapon unsuccessfully firing on the incoming comet, the ice age, and the terrorists gaining control of the satellite years later:

Causing earthquakes, tidal waves, and a dust cloud that soon covered
  most of the Northern hemisphere, it changed the face of our planet
  forever. Leaving Russia destroyed, and turning Europe into a
  snow-covered "death zone". 
...
When a military command center registers a long forgotten experimental
  satellite going green, an expedition is set up to find the base from
  where it is controlled.

